# Mi ASP.TextBox no acepta AutoPostBack

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap

Buenas!! Estoy trabajando con ASP.NET y en dos TextBox estoy utilizando DatetimePicker de Bootstrap. Quisiera ponerle un AutoPostBack al segundo TextBox para calcular la diferencia de tiempo de ambos y mostrarlo en otro control pero no hace nada y necesito ayuda. Gracias de antemano.

```html
<div class="form-group text-center">
                                    <label> Hora de Llegada</label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtHoraLlegada" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" 
                                    AutoPostBack="true" ontextchanged="txtHoraLlegada_TextChanged"  />
                                        <div class="input-group date">
                            </div>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        $(function () {
                                            $('#<%=txtHoraLlegada.ClientID %>').datetimepicker();
                                        });

                                    </script>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar un post de un evento desde javascript deberias usar el `__doPostBack`

[__doPostBack function](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667531/doPostBack-function)

como observaras se realzia un submit pero indicas el `EVENTTARGET` para que se redirecione al evento del control que corresponde

```
<script>
function __doPostBack( eventTarget, eventArgument )
{
    document.Form1.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
    document.Form1.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
    document.Form1.submit();
}
</script>
```

Deberias en tu caso asociar algun evento al `datetimepicker` para capturar cuando se selecciona una fecha y alli invocar el __doPostBack